# How to select next item of an observable after catching an error?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I'n reading a stream of data from a TCP Endpoint. This may error, or go down, at which point I'd like to try connecting to a secondary endpoint.

I'd like to use Observable.Repeat to create an infinite list of endpoints, and then select one of these to create a stream.  On error, I'd like to switch to the next one.  How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit of trouble is in keeping the state of which source was in use while a re-subscription takes place. There might be a better alternative than using the `IEnumerator`, but it might not be using `Retry` semantics.

```
            //sample source which throws an error after 5 entries
            Func<string, IObservable<string>> sampleSource =
                endpoint =>
                Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
                .Select(i => $"{endpoint} : {i + 1}")
                .Take(5)
                .Concat(Observable.Throw<string>(new Exception()));

            //infinite sequence of sources
            var endpoints = new string[] { "source1", "source2" }.Repeat();

            var sequence =
            Observable.Using
            (
                endpoints.GetEnumerator,
                enumerator => Observable.Create<string>(observer =>
                {
                    enumerator.MoveNext();
                    observer.OnNext(enumerator.Current);
                    return Disposable.Empty;
                })
                .SelectMany(sampleSource)
                .Retry()
           );

            sequence.Subscribe(c => Console.WriteLine(c));

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
source1 : 1
source1 : 2
source1 : 3
source1 : 4
source1 : 5
source2 : 1
source2 : 2
source2 : 3
source2 : 4
source2 : 5
source1 : 1
source1 : 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Some sample code would be helpful, so answerers don't have to make stuff up and sprinkle in bad movie references...

```
void Main()
{
    var initialObservable = new Subject<int>();
    var observableToContinueWithAfterError = Observable.Return(10);
    var chainedObservable = initialObservable.Catch(observableToContinueWithAfterError);

    chainedObservable.Subscribe(
        i => Console.WriteLine(i), 
        e => Console.WriteLine("Too bad AC ain't in charge no more (this won't happen, Observable.Catch swallows the exception)."),
        () => Console.WriteLine("Keep the change you..."));
    initialObservable.OnNext(1);
    initialObservable.OnNext(2);
    initialObservable.OnError(new Exception());
}
```

See [here](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html#Catch) for more info on `Observable.Catch`.